# Отслеживание изменение в папке: FindFirstChangeNotification

Tags: c++, winapi

Написал функцию (не думаю, что правильно), которая отслеживает изменения в папке:

```
bool if_changes(wstring path) {
    path += L"\\";
    LPWSTR lpath = const_cast<LPWSTR>(path.c_str());
    HANDLE hDir = CreateFileW(lpath,
        FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY,
        FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_DELETE | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
        NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
        NULL);

    BYTE outBuffer[5120];
    VOID *pBuf = (BYTE*)&outBuffer;
    DWORD InfoNotify;
    BOOL ResultReadChange;
    DWORD outSize = sizeof(outBuffer);
    HANDLE ReadChange;

    ReadChange = FindFirstChangeNotificationW(lpath,
        TRUE,
        FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME |
        FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_DIR_NAME |
        FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SIZE);

    ResultReadChange = FindNextChangeNotification(ReadChange);
    FindCloseChangeNotification(ReadChange);
    return  ResultReadChange;
}
```

В основном цикле программы по условию наличия изменений в папку выполняю довольно процессоёмкие действия. Но почему-то функция постоянно видит изменения в папке, даже когда их на самом деле нет.
Пользовался `ReadDirectoryChangesW()`, но она не продолжает выполнение программы, а ждет каких-либо изменений в папке, когда мне надо проверить изменения и бежать дальше.
Собственно вопрос: что я сделал не правильно и что надо сделать, чтобы работало как в моем описании?

Answer (score 1):

Вы неправильно используете эти API. `FindNextChangeNotification()` возвращает успешность своего выполнения, но никак не наличие изменений. 
Пример использования из MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa365261(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Ну а разве успешность выполнения не подразумевает, что в папке произошли изменения?

Comment: @Y.Volegov нет. Это значит что API-функция отработала корректно. Эти API требуют использования Wait-функций (как и написано в MSDN), а не работают как вы от них ожидаете.